# What is imgMain control in visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6, controls

I'm using a VB6 application as a reference and have come across imgMain. I'm assuming its an image control, however, I cannot find the object on any of the forms. It's used to load the image. I'm just not sure what's going on with this. I'm assuming its an IMAGE CONTROL, but I cannot find this on any of the forms? it's mentioned a lot of times in teh application as it lets you view incoming faxes and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a look on source code i assume It might be custom user control that was created for some reasons probably to extend basic picturebox control.

One thing i can advise you is to further inspect code and dig to code of this custom control. If code for this control is not available then see what methods and properties instances of that particular control uses and compare them with regular picturebox.

Comment: it looks likes its in an mdicontainer, because if i look at the code it says me.imgmain, but It's not defined/declared anywhere. If i type me.imgmain.(here I'm supposed to see a menU) well I don't see any menu. It's not being recognized. I have no idea what it is. It is an enhanced method for picture boxes (zooming in/out and such)

Comment: @barry17: My VB 6.0 is bit rusty, it might be call to some OCX or DLL that contains this particular control and you won't be able to dig in to source code. Try to inspect code and locate source of that control, see through vbp files, if you locate control then maybe you will be able to contact its vendor and get some documentation